# Calculate attributes to table based on other attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I am going through thousands and thousands of road lines and giving them a value based on QC with imagery.  So for instance for the add_data field I give it one of these five numbers:

- 0 = not examined
- 1 = include
- 2 = consider excluding
- 3 = exclude
- 4 = DC

But for each of these I also need to fill out comments and type of road data.  So I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the comment and other fields based on the add_value field? So maybe it might look like this for the add data:

"1" = "include" comment = looks good  RD_Typ = Major Road.
  "2" = "include" comment = looks good  RD_Typ = Dirt Road.
  "3" = "include" comment = Joined data to other data  RD_Typ = Major Road.
  "4" = "include" comment =  Joined data to other data = Dirt Road.

..... and so on you get the point.  So the question is can I calculate the other fields based on the number I calculate in the add data field.  I know I could do this with a join and then calc field but that just does not seem to be as much fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have no problem calculating a field based on another.  One way to accomplish this is through the field calculator directly.  You can also easily incorporate calculations such as this using stand-alone Python scripting.  I've attached a screenshot from ESRI's [Calculate Field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/) that will hopefully get you started.  Keep in mind you will have to add to the pre-logic script code slightly by adding `elif` statements to account for all of your variables.

[image]

Another example in python from the same [source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/):

```
Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
  if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
    return 1
  elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
    return 2
  elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
    return 3
  elif (WellYield > 30):
    return 4
```